# Wave equation for finite-length with fixed ends

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose I have a PDE to describe the vibration $u(x,t)$ of a string of length $L$ with fixed ends:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt} - a^2 u_{xx} = f(x,t), & 0<x<L, \, t>0, \\
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0, & t \ge 0, \\
u(x,0)=\phi_0(x), \, u_t(x,0)=\phi_1(x), & 0\le x \le L.
\end{cases}
$$
Using separation of variables, I can find its general solution to the homogeneous equation:
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( A_k \cos \frac{k \pi at}{L} + B_k \sin \frac{k \pi at}{L} \right) \sin \frac{k \pi x}{L},
$$
where $A_k$ and $B_k$ can be found by the initial conditions with the Fourier expansion.

I'm trying to understand **how to create only one mode to have standing wave**.

1. When $\phi_0(x)=\phi_1(x)=0$, is there a way to describe a force (like a sine function) acting at $x=0$ of the string, and the wave will be traveling to the right? What is the solution formula?

Can I change the boundary to the sine-wave function of $t$ for one end to achieve this?  I tried $A \sin \frac{k \pi at}{L}$ but the answer has many modes.

Should I switch back to d'Alembert formula?

2. Is there a way to write a solution of the wave traveling to the right, hitting the other end, and coming back?  I looked up, and it seemed like people just manually switch $A \sin(kx-wt)$ to $A \sin(kx+wt+\pi)$.  Can we do it automatically in math (e.g., when $t$ is large, the function will change) by separation of variables method?

Thank you. I'm sorry I'm not good at physics at all.

EDIT: I tried to do C2 and C3 on page 3 as in this article: [article](https://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/%7Ejameshet/IntroLabs/IntroLabDocuments/150-12%20Waves/Waves%209.0.pdf)